# ModuleNotFoundError when i use python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.6

Some modules (for example lxml) return `ModuleNotFoundError` when I run code with them using `python3` command. But when I use `python3.6` command everything works well. Why it is so?

P.S.
`python3 --version` returns `Python 3.7.2`

Comment: That means, you have both python 3.7 and python 3.6 installed but that particular module is only installed for python 3.6 version, not for python 3.7

Comment: @ArkistarvhKltzuonstev why pip3 installs only for 3.6?

Answer (score 2):

This is due to your `environment variables` pointing python to 3.7.2 you probably have python 3.6 installed too but your `python` is pointing to 3.7.2.

You can change it under the computer environment variables and changing to path of your python to your 3.6